# OctoberCms Missing default sorting key in the model class

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-backend

In OctoberCMS backend, I have created a controller and a model (Addresses) using the scaffold command lines, set the configuration for (columns and fields yaml files), and when trying to open the update page for a record, it gives me this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sort_order' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `directory_subject_address` where `directory_subject_address`.`id` = 1016 order by `sort_order` asc limit 1)" on line 664 of PathToMyLocalProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php

I don't have `sort_order` key in my DB table.

I think it might be missing the default sort key in the model class.

Answer (score 2):

During scaffold I guess `sortable` behavior is added.

So, If you need `Sortable behavior` your table need to have field `sort_order`.

> If you don't want then just remove `ReorderController` behavior from controller and `October\Rain\Database\Traits\Sortable OR October\Rain\Database\Traits\NestedTree` trait from model (in your case Addresses model).

reference information : https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/reorder.

if any doubt  please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer is correct and worked for more me, to solve this issue (while keeping the Sortable trait) just found in [Traits - October CMS](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/traits#sortable):

> You may modify the key name used to identify the sort order by defining the SORT_ORDER constant: `const SORT_ORDER = 'my_sort_order_column';`

To have the model class like this:

```
class MyModel extends Model {
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Sortable;
    const SORT_ORDER = 'custom_sort_order_column';
}
```

Comment: Yes `October CMS` is very extensive it can let you extend each and very aspect of it :)